# Converting 'const char [6]' to 'WCHAR**

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, can someone please help me solve this error:
    cannot convert `'const char [6]'` to `'WCHAR** {aka wchar_t**}'`

My code is as follows:

```
const char name[]   = "madz";
void method1(LPCWSTR lpServer, LPWSTR* lpNameBuffer,
        PNETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS BufferType)
{

    lpNameBuffer = name;
    return NERR_Success;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you just need `const wchar_t name[] = L"madz";`, no conversion is needed.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Its not that I havent tried. I have tried both the answers given below. For some reason it doesnt seem to work!

Comment: @Madz I assume that Luchian suggested that you first try tackling the problem _on your own_, at least Googling for an answer before asking.

Comment: By the way, don't forget to take the address of your string: `lpNameBuffer = &name;`

Comment: That's not a very specific answer. What doesn't work when trying the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like [`mbstowcs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx):

```
char input[6] ="qwerty";
wchar_t output[6];
mbstowcs( output, input, 6 );
```

The code above will convert the "qwerty" string into `wchar_t` and put it into the *output* array.

Answer (score 0):

Use MultiByteToWideChar function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202786.aspx